# on the rds of aws you can schedule tasks for the database (postgresql)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

I have an instance of postgres in rds and I want to know if you can schedule tasks as you do in the crontab

Comment: what kind of tasks do you want to schedule exactly? what have you tried?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agree with @danimal your question is a little strange. With AWS you can schedule tasks with CloudWatch rules, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html. If you're using Docker their is also scheduling features in ECS, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html. Their is no scheduling feature in RDS.